# Four dice showing 3 values

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, dice

I have 4 different color dice: blue, red, yellow and green.
I need to check how many possibilities we get if the set of the numbers that are on the dices consists of 3 distinct numbers. In other words, 1 dice is equal to another and the other two are different.

I have 2 answers in my mind and I'm not sure which is right:

- first : 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 (the last one is the 1 of the three options on the 3 dices we chose) so its 360.
- second : 6 * 5 * 4 * 6 (lets say we choose the first, 6 options, then the next one is the same so 1 option, after its going to be 5 options and than 4 options, and we do this 6 times...) so i get 720. exactly double.

I am not sure which one is right and why. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3$ would refer either to the number of ways all four dice can have distinct numbers or can refer to the number of ways you have a total of three distinct numbers on four dice however it is guaranteed that (say for example) the red die is always going to be one of the matched dice.

Answer (score 1):

Step one: pick which two colored dice match.  $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ possibilities

Step two: pick what number is on the matching dice.  $6$ possibilities

Step three: pick the number of the unmatched die with the color earliest in lexigraphical order (I.e., if the green and yellow dice are the matching pair, I will choose the number for the blue die in step three, but if blue green are the matching pair I will choose the number for the red die in step three).    $5$ possibilities (since we could not choose the same number as what we chose for the matching pair in step 2)

Step four: pick the number of the final unmatched die.  $4$ possibilities (since we could not choose the number in step three or the number used in step 2)

For a final total of $6\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4$ possibilities.

Comment: Nice. Do you need the detailed instruction for choosing the next die after the first two?

Comment: @Joffan:  it is the only one left

Comment: @RossMillikan I meant the third die, the one after the identical pair.

Comment: @Joffan Arguably not, but it is nice to be explicit when detailing how the process goes.  You could edit step three to be "pick one of the remaining die and take note of its color, then pick the number for it.  Record the result in the slot intended for that color."  The benefit of writing it the way I did is that it lends easily to a sequence of choices that leads to only one result ({blue&red, 3, 5, 1} corresponds to blue=3, green=5, red=3, yellow=1).  If the die selected in step 3 was chosen randomly we might have trouble telling apart from {blue&red, 3, 5, 1} and {blue&red, 3, 1, 5}.